# how to Play a sound file stocked in a data base Access

Tags: c#

Hello
Please can you give me the code that allows me to read a file.wav ("alarme.wav") stored in a database, I tried the following code:

```
private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection ("DSN = cp1");
cn.Open ();
OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand ("select path from WHERE Code Alarm alarm = 32 ",     cn);
cmd1.Connection = cn;
fileName = cmd1.ToString ();
WaveOut wave = new ();
wave.DeviceNumber = 0;
playSound (0);
```

But he gave me the following error:
"Could not find file 'C: \ Users \ wafa \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2010 \ Projects \ ALARMED \ ALARMED \ bin \ Debug \ System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand'."
At the line:
"waveReader = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader (fileName);" in my "playSound" function:

```
public void PlaySound (int deviceNumber)
{
disposeWave ();// stop previous sounds Before Starting
waveReader = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader (fileName);
var waveOut NAudio.Wave.WaveOut = new ();
waveOut.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
var output = waveOut;
output.Init (waveReader);
output.Play ();
}
```

Thank you in advance.
Good day :)

Comment: Is the sound file really stored in the database? By the looks of it, it seems like only the path to the file is stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you get this done via

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer Player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(fileName)
Player.Play();
```

Comment: Thank you for replying :) but I cant use this function because I implement with NAudio

Answer (score 0):

While I can't give you a "Ready To Go" solution, I would suggest you put a breakpoint on your error line, and you check the value of "fileName". If it's the correct path, then the way you use the path is wrong. If the path is wrong, then you need to fix the way you extract the path before you try to play the wave.

Edit 1 & 2 Combined:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    #region Fields & Properties
    Dictionary<int, string> _soundFilepaths;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor & Destructor
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.EnableSounds();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    private void playSound1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.PlaySound(0, 1);
    }

    private void playSound2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.PlaySound(0, 2);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    private void EnableSounds()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> soundPaths = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        string commandString = "select code_alarme, chemin from alarme";

        using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=cp1"))
        {
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(commandString, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                conn.Open();

                using (OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        soundPaths.Add(int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()), dr[1].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this._soundFilepaths = soundPaths;
    }

    private void PlaySound(int deviceID, int soundID)
    {
        // I don't have the NAudio library so I can't check if it works or no though.
        disposeWave();
        NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader waveReader = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(this._soundFilepaths[soundID]);
        var waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut();
        waveOut.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
        var output = waveOut;
        output.Init(waveReader);
        output.Play();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: @Tipx:Thank you very match,I'll try this :)

Comment: @nicolecastel: So, how does the story ends? Don't let us hanging there!

Comment: @Tipx: this code works for me: " private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          OdbcDataReader dr;
            OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=cp1");
            cn.Open();
            OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand("select chemin from alarme where code_alarme=41", cn);
            cmd1.Connection = cn;
           
           dr =cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            fileName = dr.GetString(0);
            wave = new WaveOut();
             wave.DeviceNumber = 0;
            playSound(0);
        }

Comment: Excellent alors ;-) (I'll still write in english if someone else wants to understand) For performance issues, and to do things properly, I would precache all the paths to sound files in a Dictionary<int,string> instead of querying the database every time you want a sound to play.

Comment: @Tipx: Je ne suis pas sure que j'ai bien compris ton idée,sorry but I really didn't understand,can you explain please ?

Comment: I just edited my answer. I don't say it's the best thing to do, but that's what I would do. If you have another question, feel free to ask!

Comment: when I try to run my program in another pc it dont works and as you said for performance issue,it's not very pratic to ask every user to create his ODBC before using the application,so please can you explain more your idea????? And if you can can you give me an example????

Comment: Well, your form constructor could call EnableSounds(). My point is that with your code, EVERY time you click, your application creates a connection, connects to the database, runs a query, read the result, THEN play the sound. If you precache all the filepaths for the sounds you want to play, you'll save a lot of back and forth with the database. If I can get a free minute today, I'll try to modify my example.

Comment: Also, when you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Where does it stops? What's the exception?

Comment: When I run my code in another machine the exception is that he can't found the cp1 so I should create an ODBC an I should call it "cp1"  in the other pc if I want to run my code. And thank you very much for the code,this is very gentel from you.I'll try to use it and I'll tell you the result :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd1.ToString ();
```

That looks veeery wrong. The IDBCommand exposes methods like `ExecuteRead()` or `ExecuteScalar()` and the like.

The default implementation of `ToString()` is to output the type name. Unless you have a file called "**System.Data.OdbcCommand**" in your working directory you won't hear much, I'm afraid...

Comment: LOL, just now I read fully your question...seems I got the namespace wrong!

Comment: I used  "fileName = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();" but it doesn't work too

Comment: get the reader from the command and access the first row/column. THere are loads of example son the internet by searching for dbcommand + executereader